# EnableEurekaClient import doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

> I added spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client gradle depedency in
> my project and shrik the depedency. But when go use
> @EnableEurekaClient in my Main class it show me  suggestion create
> @EnableEurekaClient annotation. Don't show any import file of eureka
> client.

```
Unresolved reference: EnableEurekaClient
```

> productserviceApplication.kt

```
  package com.main.productservice
    
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
    import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableEurekaClient
    class ProductServiceApplication
    
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<ProductServiceApplication>(*args)
    }
```

> gradle.kt

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.

    kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }
    
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    
    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

> I am getting error at  @EnableEurekaClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to import the Spring Cloud BOM in your Gradle build definition:

```
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.3"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}
```

The [EnableEurekaClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/main/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EnableEurekaClient.java) annotation is in package `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka`. You should add the following import to your main application file:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient
```

Answer (score 37):

`@EnableEurekaClient` is deprecated, no need to annotate the main class. It is enough to add the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency to `pom.xml` and if we have the application name in yml or properties file it will be registered to Eureka Server.

Answer (score 14):

This is an error with version 2022.0.1, with this version you need to use @EnableDiscoveryClient or use the version 2020.0.3 for @EnableEurekaClient

Comment: or 2021.0.3 :))

Answer (score 4):

If you are using latest version of Spring boot then use `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation on Spring boot application.

1. Dependency :

   `<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-  client</artifactId> </dependency>`
2. Outside the dependencies tag :

   `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId> <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> </dependency> </dependencies> </dependencyManagement>`

3.In Properties tag :

```
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are latest version then use
**@EnableDiscoveryClient** in Place of **@EnableEurekaClient**
in main file