# Spring Cloud Gateway with Eureka Discovery not routing requests to Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on a project with multiple microservices registered with a Eureka Discovery Server. I've set up a Spring Cloud Gateway as an Eureka client and configured the routes accordingly. However, my requests through the Gateway result in 404 errors, while direct requests to the microservices succeed.

API Gateway application.properties:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8080

##Product Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/product

##Order Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/order
```

ApiGatewayMain:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Both my microservices (order-service and product-service) have server.port=0 for random port selection and are registered with Eureka:

order-service and product-service application.properties:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.application.name=order-service  # for order-service
# spring.application.name=product-service  # for product-service
```

OrderController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        orderService.placeOrder(orderRequest);
        return "Order placed successfully";
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

ProductController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;
    // ... methods ...
}
```

Issue:

When making a POST request to http://localhost:8080/api/order via Postman, I receive the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-03-08T20:08:59.340+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/order"
}
```

However, directly calling the order-service using its dynamically assigned port, such as `http://localhost:54062/api/order`, works correctly and I receive a `Order placed successfully` response.

What am I missing in my Gateway setup that's preventing it from routing requests to the microservices? Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the build configuration of api gateway

Comment: I've edited my question with all the context I have on the api-gateway @Shanan

Comment: An extra note is that I've copied the cloud version & dependencymanagement and build from the parent pom.xml into this preview. but normally those are defined in the parent pom.xml of the microservices.

Comment: Please try <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId> instead of <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>.

Comment: Oh wow, this seems to fix the issue entirely. I can now just use localhost:8080 to make the requests to a specific api route and it will be correctly routed. Thanks man, do you want to make a quick answer inside this stack overflow question so I can upvote it as the solution? @shanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

instead of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your eureka should discover all the microservices. Check here `localhost:8761`
2. Use `@EnableEurekaClient` instead of `@EnableDiscoveryClient`
3. Make sure to have regex if you are going to use a different URI from that microservice.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/order/**
```

Comment: I would like to try this, and my initial goal was to use `@EnableEurekaClient` instead of `@EnableDiscoveryClient`. But for some reason my application doesn't recognize @EnableEurekaClient nor can I import anything from it even when I have `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` in my pom.xml. When searching to a solution I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285299/enableeurekaclient-import-doesnt-exist). So I went with EnableDiscoveryClient instead. So just like right now, I can't add @EnableEurekaClient because it doesn't exist

Comment: My eureka discovery server does have every microservice up and running, shown inside the eureka dashboard without any issues. and for more context, I use spring-boot version 3.2.3.